# How to install module (airtable.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, airtable

may be this question is kinda stupid but I'm very new to js and I want to use airtable api so i download Airtable.js from https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js and I extract my file in D: and then I try to type "npm install airtable"in the node.js cmd and this error occur.

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json'
npm WARN user No description
npm WARN user No repository field.
npm WARN user No README data
npm WARN user No license field.

I think it is about path where I extract the file but I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `init`'ing your folder by typing `npm init` and filling necessary datas.
Then try `npm install airtable` again

Comment: I try to to as you say and I face another err 





npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: That's no problem, the dependency is optional :)

Comment: @NakiNakito don't forget to mark the solution as answered if it solved your problem. Thanks